# How do you fix a TeamCity shared resource lock after a hard crash?

Tags: crash, locking, teamcity, shared-resource

Background: I have a TeamCity installation with dozens of build configurations. Many of these build configurations deploy to the same servers. To alleviate any conflicts, I used TeamCity's shared resources feature to control how these builds run. All the builds that deploy to one particular server require a write lock for the same shared resource; thus, they won't try to deploy to the same server at the same time.

Over the weekend we had a hard crash due to a power outage. The crash happened while a build, which had a write lock on a shared resource, was running. Now it appears that write lock never got released. None of the builds that use that shared resource can run--they all just queue up. If I disable the resource and then re-enable it, a build will run, but the next time it will just queue up again.

I would really rather not delete and re-create these shared resources; each one is used by 6-9 build configurations, and re-assigning them all would be a huge headache. How to I clear the un-released write lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick, 
shared resource lock state is determined in runtime and is not stored anywhere. So, if there is a hanging build that requires a write lock, this can cause described behaviour. In this case you should check for hanging builds and forcibly terminate them for lock to be released

Also, there is an issue [TW-36042](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36042) in TeamCity 8.1.2 that causes resources with infinite quota to behave wrongly with write locks. If your behaviour matches that in the issue - the workaround (before 8.1.3 update) is to convert infinite resource to resource with specified quota

Comment: That was it! We upgraded to TeamCity 8.1.2 about 12 hours before the power outage. That's why it seemed like the hard crash caused the locks to get stuck; really, it was just TW-36042. When I changed the quotas to be finite, builds started running again. Thanks!